# Libvirt + Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, libvirt

Is it possible to manage the Android Emulator with libvirt?
And if possible, how?

Thanks, Adam

Comment: viewed 302 times, and nobody found an answer

Answer (score 0):

There is no libvirt driver at this time which targets the Android Emulator.